# how to get Partial Views in mvc 5 posted data?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Iam Asp.net Webform Developer and are trying to learn .net MVC 5.
I know how to make partial view with only static html tags in MVC 5.

But can i in a MVC partial View also have a form with textboxes and a submit buttion ?

If yes, so where do i write Postback function for this partial View for get its posted values ,in which controller ?

Comment: I think you should use an Editor Template instead. This can take a part of your model and assign values to them.                                                           The editor with form values will end up on the client incorporated into the html.  When the form is posted all the name value pairs will be sent and if there are corresponding names on the server Action (the model parameter) then they will be bound. In other words you will have access to the editor template values within the controller action for that main page controller.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can have text boxes and a submit button in partial view as well.

Lets say for example you have a product application, and your main page (View) is displaying all the product available. 
so in order to show the product you need to pass a model

```
@model  IList<xyzRetailer.ViewModels.ProductViewModel>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}
```

and you can read the value like:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
        <h2>Product Categories</h2>
                <ul>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Select(a=>a.Category).Distinct())
            {
                <li>@item</li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**Now to your question** if you want to have a a partial view with different view model you can go with **tuple** or you can have a new object created just for partial view while calling it like below

```
@Html.Partial("_AddProduct", new yzRetailer.ViewModels.ProductViewModel())
```

and your partial view will be something like below:

```
    @model xyzRetailer.ViewModels.ProductViewModel
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
     <div class="input-group">
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Id, new { @class = "hidden" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Category, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div><input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" />
    }
```

And the controller code should go Home-> Create that you have mentioned in **@Html.BeginForm**.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(ProductViewModel product)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return this.BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(product.Id))
        {
            var result = await _catelogueManager.AddAsync(product);
        }
        else
        {
            var result = await _catelogueManager.UpdateAsync(product.Id, product);
        }
        var products = await _catelogueManager.GetAllAsync();
        return View("Index", products);
    }
```